# How do I find the number of matching value pairs between python lists?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out the cleanest way to find out how many matching pairs there are between two lists. Order does not matter between the two lists

*EDIT* By this I mean the order of listed pairs do not matter but [[1,2]] and [[2,1]] are NOT the same. Also, each pair is unique and no duplicates will be found. The pairs are to track relationships between adjacent nodes in a state space, therefore the order of each relationship is important. I removed the statement that length of a & b do not matter. In this case, they will always be the same. The goal is I have a state space with stacked blocks in a certain order and I need to change that order to a given outcome. In order to verify my logic, it will be important to compare relationships between the layout in the current state space and the objective layout. To do that, I thought to create a list of all relationships (i.e. block 1 to 2, block 2 to 3, etc.) for the current and objective spaces and compare the two lists to see if I am any closer to the objective.

i.e.

```
a = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1]]
b = [[1,1], [3,3], [2,1], [4,2]]

matches = 2
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please [edit] your question and post your current code? What happens when you run it, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See also [ask].

Comment: You could iterate over one list and check for each pair if it is `in` the other list.

Comment: what do you mean by order doesn't matter? that `[2,3]` and `[3,2]` should be considered equivalent?

Comment: As already pointed out, your current question is ambiguous. It is difficult to work out exactly what you want here. Can you please [edit] your question, showing some input/output pairs, and describe more explicitly what the intended behavior of your program is. It might help to also post any relevant code you have thus far, for more context.

Answer (score 2):

Set arithmetic in Python can be useful in these situations for quick, easy-to-read code. Since Python List objects are not hashable, they cannot be set members. Tuples, however, can be set members. Therefore, to use set arithmetic here, you will first need to convert the pairs to tuples. Try something like the following:

```
from typing import Set, List


def to_set_of_tuples(li: List[list]) -> Set[tuple]:
    return set(map(tuple, li))


def get_num_matching_pairs(li0: List[list], li1: List[list]) -> int:
    matching_pairs: Set[tuple] = to_set_of_tuples(a) & to_set_of_tuples(b)
    num_matching_pairs: int = len(matching_pairs)
    return num_matching_pairs


a = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1]]
b = [[1,1], [3,3], [2,1]]
assert 2 == get_num_matching_pairs(a, b)
```

You can read more about set arithmetic in Python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set). Cheers!

Comment: so if I were to simply converted this to a list of tuples and not a list of lists, it becomes hashable? I tried a method with enumerate and the error I received was about that.

Comment: @the_talon_kharde Yep! A tuple of of primitives (e.g. a tuple of integers, as utilized in my answer) is always hashable in Python. Note that a list of tuples is *not* hashable, while a tuple of tuples is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming duplicates do matter, and performance does not (this algorithm is O(n^2)):

```
def find_matches(a, b):
    matches = 0
    for a_item in a:
        for b_item in b:
            if a_item == b_item:
                matches += 1
    return matches


a = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1]]
b = [[1,1], [3,3], [2,1]]

matches = find_matches(a,b)

assert(matches) == 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming no duplicates in each list you could use `tuple`s and `set`s as follows:

```py
a = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1]]
b = [[1,1], [3,3], [2,1]]

# tuples are hashable, while lists aren't
a_set = set(tuple(x) for x in a)
b_set = set(tuple(x) for x in b)

matches = len(a_set.intersection(b_set)) # 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you wanting to check how many items in one list are also in the other? Why not:

```
sum(i in b for i in a)
```